# Javascript do-while looping problems

Tags: javascript

I need help with looping the javascript in a do/while statement loop.

The problems I am having is that I don't want to display the incorrect information in my table when entering an invalid product, but it does display in the document.write. I need help in order to make sure that the incorrect information won't be displayed.

Also, when I hit "ok" to add more to my order, it doesn't loop it but merely displays the document.write. I want it to loop if you hit the "ok" button.

Thank you for the help.

Here is the code:

```
 <html>

    <head><title>Javascript Assignment 3: Daniel Weiner</title>
      </head>
    <body bgcolor="brown">

    <h1 align="center">Big Ben's Burgers-eCommerce</h1> 

    <table border="1" width="100%" height="450px" bgcolor="gray"><tr>
      <th align="center">Product/Service</th>
      <th align="center">Price</th>
      <th align="center">Discount</th>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="orange">
      <td align="center"><font size="3">Hamburger 
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/food/product_nutrition.sandwiches.256.Hamburger.html" target="_blank">Classic Hamburger</a>

      <td align="right" bgcolor="orange"><font size="3">$8.00</font></td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="orange"><font size="3">.10</font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="orange">
      <td align="center"><font size="3">Cheeseburger
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/food/product_nutrition.sandwiches.284.cheeseburger.html" target="_blank">Classic Cheeseburger  </a>
    </font></td>
      <td align="right" bgcolor="orange"><font size="3">$9.00</font></td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="orange"><font size="3">.05</font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="orange">
      <td align="center"><font size="3">Soda
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/food/full_menu/beverages.html" target="_blank">Fabulous Drinks</a>
    </font></td>
      <td align="right" bgcolor="orange"><font size="3">$2.00
    </font></td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="orange"><font size="3"> .07</font></td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="red">
      <td align="center"><font size="3"> French Fries
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/food/product_nutrition.snackssides.120.small-french-fries.html" target="_blank"> Fries</a>
    </font></td>
      <td align="right" bgcolor="red"><font size="3"> $4.00</font></td>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="red"><font size="3">.15</font></td>

    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*Daniel Weiner, Fengpeng Yuan, Javascript 2, Nov 4,2011*/

    var username;
    var bprice= 8;
    var chprice= 9;
    var sprice= 2;
    var fprice= 4;
    var price= 0;
    var a;
    var b;
    var product= "hamburger, cheeseburger, soda, fries";
    var quantity =0;
    var total;
    var cost = 0;
    var discount= 0;
    do{
    username =prompt("Welcome to Big Ben's Burgers. Please enter your name.", "");
    alert("Hello " + username+". Please look through our available products and services before placing your order.","");
    product=prompt("What do you want?","");

    quantity =1*prompt("How many of " +product+ " would you like?");




    if (product == "hamburger")
    {   
    price = bprice; 

    discount = .1;
    }
    else if (product == "cheeseburger")
    {   
    price = chprice;

    discount = .05;
    }

    else if (product == "soda")
    {   
    price = sprice;

    discount = .07;
    }

    else if (product == "fries")
    {   
    price = fprice;

    discount = .15;
    }   

    else{
        alert("Sorry, " +username+  " Your item not found.");
    }
        cost=price*quantity
        discount=price*discount*quantity
        total=cost-discount
    document.write("The cost of buying " +quantity+ " of " +product+ " is $" +cost+ ".<br/>");
    document.write("This discount for this purchase is $" +discount+ ".<br/>");

    }while(a==false)
    a = confirm("Do you want to place another order?");

    (b==false)
    document.write("Thank you for placing an order with us, " +username+ ".<br/>");
    document.write("The total order cost is $" +total+ ".");

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I retagged this as [tag:javascript] - Java and Javascript have as much in common as a car and a carrot.

Answer (score 0):

for the second part of the question, you have to use the statement bellow in the loop

```
 a = confirm("Do you want to place another order?");
```

Comment: where do i put the a=confirm("do you want to place another order?"); do i make another else if statement or do i put it in the else statement

Comment: if you want to ask for the confirmation, that statement should go in the loop. in your case, end of the do{} statement, before closing it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't conditioning the part that outputs the result on whether or not a valid product was selected. You need something like the following;

```
do{
    ....

    productValid = false;

    if (product == "hamburger")
    {   
    price = bprice; 

    discount = .1;
    productValid = true;

    }
    else if (product == "cheeseburger")
    {   
    price = chprice;

    discount = .05;
productValid = true;

    }

    else if (product == "soda")
    {   
    price = sprice;

    discount = .07;
productValid = true;
    }

    else if (product == "fries")
    {   
    price = fprice;

    discount = .15;
productValid = true;
    }   

    else{
        alert("Sorry, " +username+  " Your item not found.");
    }

if(productValid){
        cost=price*quantity
        discount=price*discount*quantity
        total=cost-discount
    document.write("The cost of buying " +quantity+ " of " +product+ " is $" +cost+ ".<br/>");
    document.write("This discount for this purchase is $" +discount+ ".<br/>");
}
else
{
    document.write("No valid product selected<br>");
}
 a = confirm("Do you want to place another order?");

    }while(a==true)
```

Comment: Also, as the others have stated, the confirm() for placing another order should happen inside the do-while, and the condition to check for would be while(a==true), since you want it to loop again if they choose yes.

Comment: Tip: start your loop with `productValid = true;` and change it to false if its *not* found. That way you don't have to write it several times.

Comment: Agreed, though you can argue either way on that one. I usually prefer my original approach because it makes more sense when reading through the code (product is not valid until explicitly check), at the cost of some extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-iterating the loop if the user hits `cancel`. Change `while(a==false)` to `while(a==true)` or simply `while(a)`

Also put the line

```
a = confirm("Do you want to place another order?");
```

as the last line **in** your loop, instead of the line after.

You can set a flag var that lets you know if the item was found or not and check it at the end of your loop to avoid displaying data for non-existing items:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*Daniel Weiner, Fengpeng Yuan, Javascript 2, Nov 4,2011*/

    var username;
    var bprice= 8;
    var chprice= 9;
    var sprice= 2;
    var fprice= 4;
    var price= 0;
    var a;
    var b;
    var product= "hamburger, cheeseburger, soda, fries";
    var quantity =0;
    var total;
    var cost = 0;
    var discount= 0;
    var flag;

    do{
    flag = true;  //assume found unless otherwise
    username =prompt("Welcome to Big Ben's Burgers. Please enter your name.", "");
    alert("Hello " + username+". Please look through our available products and services before placing your order.","");
    product=prompt("What do you want?","");
    quantity =1*prompt("How many of " +product+ " would you like?");

    if (product == "hamburger")
    {   
    price = bprice; 

    discount = .1;
    }
    else if (product == "cheeseburger")
    {   
    price = chprice;

    discount = .05;
    }

    else if (product == "soda")
    {   
    price = sprice;

    discount = .07;
    }

    else if (product == "fries")
    {   
    price = fprice;

    discount = .15;
    }   
    else{
        alert("Sorry, " +username+  " Your item not found.");
        flag = false;
    }

    if(flag){
        cost=price*quantity
        discount=price*discount*quantity
        total=cost-discount
        document.write("The cost of buying " +quantity+ " of " +product+ " is $" +cost+ ".<br/>");
        document.write("This discount for this purchase is $" +discount+ ".<br/>");
    }
    a = confirm("Do you want to place another order?");
    }while(a);
    alert('goodbye');
    </script>
```